# What does 'getSender()` mean in Akka?

Tags: java, akka, actor

Now I am learning Akka a little bit, but I can't understand the exact meaning of `getSender()`.
In [this official document,](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/UntypedActor.html) the method `getSender()` is used and the explanation is like

`// Reply to original sender of message
 getSender().tell(msg + ":" + getSelf());`

This seems to be a response method, so this actor has to respond to a actor who sent a message and that method is what does it actually.  And I am confused because I don't understand  whether `getSender()` affords the receiver actor or the sender actor.  So, could you give me an explanation about it?

Thanks.

```
public class WebSocketActor extends UntypedActor {

/**
 * Actor's reference
 */
private final static ActorRef ref = Akka.system().actorOf(new Props(WebSocketActor.class));

/**
 * the list of those who should get messages
 */
Map<String, WebSocket.Out<JsonNode>> members = new HashMap<String, WebSocket.Out<JsonNode>>();

/**
 * a method adding a certain user
 * @param username a user name
 * @param in receive of WebSokcet
 * @param out sending of WebSocket
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void join(final String username, WebSocket.In<JsonNode> in, WebSocket.Out<JsonNode> out) throws Exception {

    // causing JOIN event 
    Boolean result = (Boolean) Await.result(ask(ref, new Message(username, "", "", WebSocketEvent.JOIN, out), 1000), Duration.create(1, SECONDS));

    if(result) {
        // if a message is sent,MESSAGE event will occur.
        in.onMessage(new Callback<JsonNode>() {
            public void invoke(JsonNode event) {
                ref.tell(new Message(username, event.get("x").asText(), event.get("y").asText(), WebSocketEvent.MESSAGE, null), ref);
            }
        });
        // a close method when WebSocket is closed
        in.onClose(new Callback0() {
            public void invoke() {
                ref.tell(new Message(username, "", "", WebSocketEvent.QUIT, null), ref);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // sending an error
        ObjectNode error = Json.newObject();
        error.put("error", result);
        out.write(error);
    }
}

/**
 * the executable method when an event happens
 * @param message an event object
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {

    // diciding whether the object is an event or not
    Option<Message> event = EventUtil.getEvent(message);
    if(event.isDefined()){
        Message m = event.get();
        switch (m.getEventType()) {
            // adding to members
            case JOIN:
                members.put(m.getUsername(), m.getChannel());
                getSender().tell(true, ref);
                break;
            // sending all
            case MESSAGE:
                WebSocketMessenger.notifyAll(m.getUsername(), m.getX(), m.getY(), members);
                break;
            // excluding someone from members
            case QUIT:
                members.remove(m.getUsername());
                break;
            default:
                unhandled(message);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

In above code, in `onReceive(Object message)` method you can see the `getSender()` method. However, when the `join(final String username, WebSocket.In<JsonNode> in, WebSocket.Out out)` method is called, first the actor asks a new message of another actor, and then in `onReceive(Object message)` method,  another actor answers with `true` by executing like `getSender().tell(true, ref);`.  In this circumstance, `getSender()` gives the first actor who asked. Isn't it strange because the first actor who asked gives `true` to the another actor who should give `true` to the first actor?
Your answer would be very useful, but I am still not clear, sorry.

EDIT:
You said this doesn't work well, but it works.
Are you familiar with PlayFramework? If so, it is totally straightforward to grasp a whole picture. This code is the controller's code which calls the `join()` method.

```
 public static WebSocket<JsonNode> ws() {
    final String username = session("username");
    return new WebSocket<JsonNode>() {
        @Override
        public void onReady(final WebSocket.In<JsonNode> in, final WebSocket.Out<JsonNode> out) {
            try {
                WebSocketActor.join(username, in, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.error("Can't connect WebSocket");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It simply returns a reference on the actor (`ActorRef`) *that just sent the message you are currently handling*.

Thus, it's a way for an actor to *answer* a message... in the code handling it.

In other words, If actor A send a message M1 to an actor B, when B calls `getSender`, it will return a reference on actor A.

**edit after code provided:**

The following won't work properly:

```
Boolean result = (Boolean) Await.result(ask(ref, new Message(username, "", "", WebSocketEvent.JOIN, out), 1000), Duration.create(1, SECONDS));
```

You can't `ask()` and expect a response from an actor, *if you're not actor yourself*. The `join()` method is static and completely executed outside the actor system! it could (and should) be in another class.

This is why `getSender()` doesn't makes sense here : there is no "akka" sender.

Comment: I understand the return value of the method `getSender()`. However, I am still not confused with some points, please see my additional question if possible.

Comment: Okay you're confused because your class is mixing up two concerns : *websocket event handling* with *actor message handling*.

Moreover, the ask() in the join method won't work - because the ask() is not called by an akka actor, but a static method!

therefore, the getSender() won't return an actor reference, since the origin of the message is not an actor. Do you see what i mean?

Comment: There are vast amount of information, let me see...    First, what do you mean by _websocket event handling with actor message handling_?  Can you be more specific?  Second, I can understand what you say maybe,namely it is not good, not following Akka's theory. And in fact what should I interpret this code?  Do you have any idea?